# How do I use CSS 3 border-radius for creating complex shapes?

Tags: html, css, shapes, css-shapes

I'm making this shape using css3. But I could not find an elegant solution to make it. I have tried some samples from css3shapes, but those are pretty simple. How do i go about drawing such a complex shape.

[image]

Comment: An image would be much easier to make and implement

Comment: You shouldn't even try building this with `border-radius`. Why not use SVG or canvas or an image?

Comment: i cannot use image. I am trying to implement it using css3, but not such an expert.

Comment: It is not what you are asking for, but in this page you can find some tricks to make border-radius more powerful creating outer border radius: http://orderedlist.com/blog/articles/flared-borders-with-css/ Maybe it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible with one element and `border-radius`

Border radius only accepts 8 arguments like this

```
    border-top-left-radius: 1px 2px;
   border-top-right-radius: 3px 4px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 5px 6px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 7px 8px;
```

You can't to any more than that.

Plus a element/box only has 4 corners, that shape must have at least 10 corners.

Might be a bad idea, but you could use `border-image` if you don't wan't it as a background.

Or use SVG

Answer (score 0):

Try border-radius-shape syntax. Coming to you in the near future.
Try it here first. http://leaverou.github.io/border-corner-shape/